# feGaussianBlur is not working properly on Safari or IE?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-filters

I have checked that feGaussianBlur is supported in Safari but why is it not showing the blur effect on the browser? Can anybody shed some light on this?

Is there something missing or additional checking need to be done especially for Safari and IE? It working well on Google Chrome and Firefox.

```css
#container {
 margin: 0 auto
 border:1px solid #fff;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 50%;
}

.cssload-dots {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 filter: url(#goo);
  -o-filter: url(#goo);
  -ms-filter: url(#goo);
  -webkit-filter: url(#goo);
  -moz-filter: url(#goo);
}

.cssload-dot {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

.cssload-dot:before {
 content: "";
 width: 34px;
 height: 34px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 49px;
 -moz-border-radius: 49px;
 border-radius: 49px;
 background: rgb(251,211,1);
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 margin-left: -17.5px;
 margin-top: -17.5px;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(5):before {
 z-index: 100;
 width: 44.5px;
 height: 44.5px;
 margin-left: -21.75px;
 margin-top: -21.75px;
 animation: cssload-dot-colors 3s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-colors 3s ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-colors 3s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-colors 3s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-colors 3s ease infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(1) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 3s 0s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 3s 0s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 3s 0s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 3s 0s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 3s 0s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(1):before {
 background-color: rgb(255,50,112);
 animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0s ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0s ease infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(2) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 3s 0.75s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 3s 0.75s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 3s 0.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 3s 0.75s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 3s 0.75s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(2):before {
 background-color: rgb(32,139,241);
 animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0.75s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0.75s ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0.75s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0.75s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 0.75s ease infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(3) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 3s 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 3s 1.5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 3s 1.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 3s 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 3s 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(3):before {
 background-color: rgb(175,225,2);
 animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 1.5s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 1.5s ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 1.5s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 1.5s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 1.5s ease infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(4) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 3s 2.25s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 3s 2.25s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 3s 2.25s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 3s 2.25s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 3s 2.25s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(4):before {
 background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 2.25s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 2.25s ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 2.25s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 2.25s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 3s 2.25s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  transform: translateY(-68px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -o-transform: translateY(-68px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-68px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-68px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-68px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
 25% {
  background-color: rgb(255,50,112);
 }
 50% {
  background-color: rgb(32,139,241);
 }
 75% {
  background-color: rgb(175,225,2);
 }
 100% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
 25% {
  background-color: rgb(255,50,112);
 }
 50% {
  background-color: rgb(32,139,241);
 }
 75% {
  background-color: rgb(175,225,2);
 }
 100% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
 25% {
  background-color: rgb(255,50,112);
 }
 50% {
  background-color: rgb(32,139,241);
 }
 75% {
  background-color: rgb(175,225,2);
 }
 100% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
 25% {
  background-color: rgb(255,50,112);
 }
 50% {
  background-color: rgb(32,139,241);
 }
 75% {
  background-color: rgb(175,225,2);
 }
 100% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
 25% {
  background-color: rgb(255,50,112);
 }
 50% {
  background-color: rgb(32,139,241);
 }
 75% {
  background-color: rgb(175,225,2);
 }
 100% {
  background-color: rgb(251,211,1);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="cssload-dots">
  <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
  <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
  <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
  <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
  <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<svg>
 <defs>
  <filter id="goo">
   <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="12" />
   <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
   <!-- <feBlend in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" ></feBlend> -->
  </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I suspect neither of these browsers support SVG filters being applied to non-SVG content.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible things:

1. feColorMatrix should have `type="matrix"` (mode is for feBlend)
2. Safari used to have a bug where you had to put your SVG
   definitions earlier in the document than when the class was used. I
   thought they had fixed this - but mentioned it in case there has
   been a regression.
3. You should always put an unprefixed version of
   a prefixed CSS property at the end of your prefixed versions. I
   don't know if Safari has unprefixed filters, but if they have (and
   EOL'd -webkit) then it won't know what to do.

IE/Edge doesn't support the use of SVG filters via CSS yet, so this isn't supposed to work in MSFT browsers.